# How do I limit characters in UITextView ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview, character

I have been looking for solutions and found the following piece of code. But I do not know how to use it, unfortunately.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string {
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        return (newLength > 25) ? NO : YES;
    }
```

**Just for testing purposes I set up an `IBACTION`**

```
-(IBAction)checkIfCorrectLength:(id)sender{
    [self textView:myTextView shouldChangeTextInRange: ?? replacementText: ?? ];

}
```

What do I pass for `shouldChangeTextInRange` and `replacementText` ? 
Or am I getting it completely wrong ?

Comment: That is a delegation method - read the documentation of UITextView and its protocols.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` from `checkIfCorrectLength:` doesn't make sense.  If you want to test the length from multiple methods, factor the test out into its own method:

```
- (BOOL)isAcceptableTextLength:(NSUInteger)length {
    return length <= 25;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string {
    return [self isAcceptableTextLength:textField.text.length + string.length - range.length];
}

-(IBAction)checkIfCorrectLength:(id)sender{
    if (![self isAcceptableTextLength:self.textField.text.length]) {
        // do something to make text shorter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi I found and modified the code here. So for xamarin users. try the following:

```
textView.ShouldChangeText += delegate
{
   if(textView.Text.Length > 159) // limit to one sms length
   {
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't call this method yourself, the text view calls it whenever it's about to change its text. Just set the text view's `delegate` property (e.g. to your view controller) and implement the method there.

Answer (score 0):

If the current object is the delegate of the text view, then you can use the following snippet:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    return weightTextView.text.length + text.length - range.length < 7;
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
if([text length] == 0)
{
    if([textView.text length] != 0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
else if([[textView text] length] > your limit value ) 
{
    return NO;
}
return YES;

}
```